# How do I setup Redis for hardware failures?

Tags: asp.net, redis, load-balancing, failover, redis-sentinel

I am implementing a caching solution for our business. I have 3 linux boxes and I am going to set up sentinel for redundancy/HA ..etc. The configuration looks pretty straight forward. For our current web services we do load balancing by sending incoming requests to multiple servers (weighted round robin...etc). With the Redis implementation I am not sure how to go about setting up a hardware failover.

Do I handle hardware failover on the client side (stackexchange redis) to move to the slave node if the master machine is down?

Edit:

I forgot to mention...
Will setting the connectionmultiplexer like this automatically handle hardware failover?

ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("server1:6379,server2:6379");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to test this and it was working as expected with the connection multiplexer - verifying that it would fail-over when one of the servers was down.